# How to animate move of SubView from one view to the other?

Tags: iphone, uiview

how i can move a subview in a UIView to out of UIView frame, and see that value of outside in bottom! sorry please see my picture for understand, i dont want to use scrollview, and dont use duplicate views to do this.

[image]

thanks

Comment: i think you want to move this subview up side in your main view right?? then use my answer for this requirement

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i dont want to bring my subview on main view, i just want when i move my subview out of the main view, the value my subview is outside, can see that in bottom of main view like above pic :)

Comment: use my answer dude just set y with -100 or whatever which you want dude  see the code bellow

Comment: @ParasJoshi ,i know what do you say but if you see the above pic again, you see while the subview is going to out of main view frame, in moving time you should see that value of sub view is outside in bottom of main view..

Comment: yes dude i understand now what you want, here create two subview same after that set value alternate , just an idea dude.....

Comment: +1 for making a question and adding a good picture to help others understand it.

Comment: thanks, but how can i use one subview? this is my problem!

Comment: @ArashZeinoddini see my updated answer i think you can get some idea from it... just set frame with your requirement and you will see the output which you want dude... :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to duplicate the subview. There's no other way, because you can't add the same subview twice.

If you try to add an existing subview to another view, it will be automatically removed from it's superview.

After the view is duplicated, you can animate both of them in the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Here create same two subview , after that set frame both like bellow...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    yourSubview1.frame = CGRectMake(yourSubview1.frame.origin.x, 200, yourSubview1.frame.size.width, yourSubview1.frame.size.height);

    yourSubview2.frame = CGRectMake(yourSubview2.frame.origin.x, 400, yourSubview2.frame.size.width, yourSubview2.frame.size.height);

}
```

and after when you want to move subview at that time just call bellow code ...

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourSubview1.frame = CGRectMake(yourSubview1.frame.origin.x, yourSubview1.frame.origin.y - 100, yourSubview1.frame.size.width, yourSubview1.frame.size.height);
    yourSubview2.frame = CGRectMake(yourSubview2.frame.origin.x, yourSubview2.frame.origin.y - 100, yourSubview2.frame.size.width, yourSubview2.frame.size.height);
    //// set `y` where you want to display just like i minus the y with 100 so its move above with 100 point of y 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

This is just an example you can set this with your frame and timer ..

i hope this help you....

Comment: @ArashZeinoddini just set frame yourSubview.frame = CGRectMake(yourSubview.frame.origin.x, -100, yourSubview.frame.size.width, yourSubview.frame.size.height); and your view not display in your main UIView dude..

Comment: thanks, i used this before on my self, but how to solve this problem with one subview, i hove no idea!

Comment: You can't. Read my answer.

Comment: @EliGanem first read my edited answer dude its same like which you write in your answer dude.. :)